# Haskell: Reading expressions as Integers from ghci prompt?

Tags: haskell, types, numbers

I am experimenting with some number theoretic functions, and dealing with large integers.  However, I'd like to be able to read an expression in from the prompt.  I have a function defined by

```
factor :: Integer -> Integer
```

and if I enter

```
ghci> factor 2047
```

it works fine.  But I can't enter

```
ghci> factor 2^11-1
```

because the expression `2^11-1` is not evaluated (at the prompt) to an `Integer`.  I can get round this with

```
ghci> factor (toInteger 2^11-1)
```

but I'm wondering if there's a way to automatically have expressions read as `Integer` values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has nothing to do with needing the expression “evaluated to an `Integer` value”. Haskell evaluates any expression when it's needed, and as whichever type the environment demands.

Only, `factor 2^11-1` is *parsed* as `(factor 2)^11 - 1`, which is evidently not what you want. (There exists no subexpression `2^11-1` in there!) But `factor (2^11 - 1)` or – somewhat preferred style – `factor $ 2^11 - 1` will work just fine.

As a matter of fact, `factor (toInteger 2^11-1)` also does not what you seem to think: this is parsed as `factor ((toInteger 2)^11 - 1)`. There's totally no need to write `toInteger 2`, instead of just `2`<sup>†</sup>.

Short overview of Haskell parsing rules:

- Prefix function application always has precedence. Hence `f x^y` is parsed as `(f x)^y`, not as `f (x^y)`.

  - This works greedily from left to right. Thus, `f x y` is parsed as `(f x) y`<sup>‡</sup>, not `f (x y)`.
- Infix operators are parsed according to their *fixity*, which you can for instance look up in GHCi with `:i ^`. For instance, `infixr 8 ^` is higher than `infixl 6 -`, that's why `2^11-1` is parsed as `(2^11) - 1` and not as `2 ^ (11-1)`.

  - The `l` or `r` in the fixity indicates the direction if you chain multiple instances of the same operator. For instance, `infixr 5 :` means that `1:2:3:[]` is parsed as `1:(2:(3:[]))`, not as `((1:2):3):[]`.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Actually that's not always true. Literals like `2` are polymorphic, i.e. they can really be evaluated as whatever type you ask for. For instance, `2 * 3 + 4 * sin 5 :: Double` will carry out all the operations as floating-point multiplication / addition. Whereas `toInteger` is in fact restricted so the result must always be an integer (and if you try to use it in a setting that expects a `Double`, this will actually be a compile-time error!), i.e. it is actually equivalent to `(2 :: Integer)`.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>Though that behaves, in many ways, more like what other languages would write as `f(x,y)`. Which would also be legal in Haskell, if slightly unidiomatic. (Then `f` would actually not be a function of two arguments, but a function of a single argument which happens to be a tuple.)</sub>

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed and informed answer.  You will appreciate that I am coming to Haskell from a procedural background!  However, maybe my confusion was simply caused by not putting the right parentheses in place.